# Spring Forms - value for form:select items attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a backing bean set up for my form. This part works fine.

I have the possible values for a field already set up as a list on my backing bean. Is there a way to access this list in the context of the commandName the same way as path is used?

As an example:

(I don't want this)

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="address">
   <form:select path="country">
      <form:options items="${address.countryList}" itemValue="countryId" itemLabel="countryName" />
   </form:select>
</form:form>
```

(I want to access it this way)

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="address">
   <form:select path="country">
      <form:options items="countryList" itemValue="countryId" itemLabel="countryName" />
   </form:select>
</form:form>
```

I see a lot of examples online using the EL style ${} for the items attribute but I am wondering if someone can show me how this is done in the context of the form. For lack of a better term, I would like to access a list that is in the same 'scope' as the commandName.

Can this be done?

In case you are wondering why I want to do it this way: I have a number of forms that are inside nested loops a few levels deep so I end up with about 9 forms total that have similar (but not exact) lists so I can't use the same list each time which is why I have the list on the backing bean. The list contains the allowed values that are specific to each bean.

Answer (score 0):

No, because `path` and `items` are fundamentally different.

The TLD indicates that the `path` attribute of the form tag indicates which field the selected option should be bound to and the `items` attribute is a convenient way to generate all of the options.

Your controller is still going to need code that roughly resembles this:

```
 public String formSetup(ModelMap model) {
     //...
     model.put("countryList", backingBean.getCountryList());
     //...
     return "mySuperAwesomeView.jsp";
 }
```